# Jmeter: Class or variable not found: org.openqa.selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

Im using Jmeter 5.4.1 and in that I have added a WebDriver Sampler to automate Chrome driver using Java. My test scenario is after navigating to the webpage I want to wait for some 5-8 seconds and then proceed further. For this I am trying to implement Explicit wait in WebDriver Sampler like this:

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium);
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait);
var ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui);
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 8000);

wait.until(ui.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.className("closeCookieModal")));

//var cook = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.className("closeCookieModal"));
var cook = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.className("closeCookieModal"));
cook.click();
```

When executing this code i am getting error with Response code: 500, the error is:
Typed variable declaration : Class or variable not found: org.openqa.selenium : at Line: 21

Am i using it correctly for Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is in [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/)  and JavaScript [is not related to Java by any means](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-java-and-javascript/)

In order to get your code working you need to switch to `javascript` in the "Language" dropdown

[image]

If you're planning to use Java - re-write your code with Java syntax and choose [`groovy`](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) as the language